# sqlite How do i select using results from another select?

Tags: c#, sqlite

in SQLite with C# I want to do

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE mediaId= for each
  SELECT mediaId FROM fav WHERE userId=1 ORDER BY indx DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

The syntax is obviously incorrect. I have no idea how to use the param from one select statement in another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most direct translation of your invalid syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE mediaId IN
  (SELECT mediaId FROM fav WHERE userId=1)
ORDER BY indx DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

A better style (maybe more speedy, but I haven't measured:

```
SELECT media.* FROM media
JOIN fav USING (mediaId)
WHERE fav.userId=1 
ORDER BY media.indx DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Both of these are standard SQL, btw, and the second form in particular will tend to work well on just about any relational DB implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need there join statements:

```
SELECT * FROM fav 
WHERE fav.userId=1
LEFT JOIN media 
ON media.mediaId=fav.mediaID
ORDER BY indx DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a SQL join statement.  This would be standard T-SQL, not at all specific to SQLite.

You'd do something like this:

SELECT m.* FROM media AS m JOIN fav AS f ON m.mediaId = f.mediaID
WHERE f.userId = 1

You can add your ordering requirements on top of this.

Comment: I think this is just standard SQL not standard T-SQL. Only MS SQL and Sybase have T-SQL. Other vendors have different SQL extensions.